# Weak Key error in C# while trying to implement TripleDES

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, des, tripledes

whenever I try to run this code I get this error:
'Specified key is a known weak key for 'TripleDES' and cannot be used.'
Can someone please help me solve this issue? I would be really grateful.
Thanks.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;


    String Data = EncryptDES("041205FFFBA666CF");


static string EncryptDES(string InputText)
{
    byte[] key = new byte[] { 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02 };
    byte[] clearData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InputText);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    TripleDES alg = TripleDES.Create();
    alg.Key = key;
    alg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cs.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
    byte[] CipherBytes = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Close();
    cs.Close();
    string EncryptedData = Convert.ToBase64String(CipherBytes);
    return EncryptedData;

}
```

Comment: Why can't you use a different key!

Comment: if you are using 3DES and the first 8 bits are the same as last 8 bits, then why do use 3DES? Use DES instead- because using that 'weak' key in 3DES dont guarantee any more security than normal DES.

Comment: I understand but the this is the only key I can use, anyway I can move forward using this key?

Comment: For the posted weak key, 3DES reduces to DES. But this is probably only a test key, so it's not clear if this is also true for your real weak key. Thus check your subkeys (if K1=K2=K3 or K1=K2 or K2=K3, s. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options)). In the worst case you can always replace 3DES by three DES operations, s. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Algorithm). Since there are no Weak-Key exceptions for DES, this would be a workaround. Weak keys, DES and ECB, are of course a high security risk. BTW, `CreateDecryptor()` for encryption seems to be a bug.

Comment: @Topaco this is not a test key this is the final key that would be used. So basically I want to continue with this key, so can you please help me with how to make this program work using this key?

Comment: For the fixed code (i.e. using `alg.CreateEncryptor()` for encryption) 3DES can be replaced by DES with the key 0x0202020202020202.

Comment: Is there no way to use triple DES using this key?

Comment: As reminder, the result is the *same*! If you want to know if the weak-key-validation can be disabled for 3DES: To my knowledge no, this is hard coded, s. [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/tripledes.cs,78).

Answer (score 0):

You can check your key with `TripleDES.IsWeakKey(Byte[])` method.

As the error speaks for itself, the key you provided is weak. Since all the bytes in the array are equal. Simply, just change the key.

For additional information, you may check [TripleDES.IsWeakKey(Byte[]) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.isweakkey) and [weak key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_key)

Comment: Actually the key can't be changed, I want to move forward with this key only, anyway I can do that?